# How to get the top records and have a different condition in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, conditional-statements

I need to have the top most record of 'RouteID' who has also the most 'Economy Price' in the total.

I already tried this code:

```
SELECT RouteID
     , Count (RouteID ) 
  FROM [Session6].[dbo].[Schedules]
 Group 
    by RouteID 
 Order 
    by count(RouteID ) DESC
```

But the result is this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24yBc.png)

The result are only the top most count of 'RouteID' not the most sum of 'EconomyPrice'

This is the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttdb9.png)

Comment: You need to clarify because the results look correct - they are ordered by the count...and there is no `EconomyPrice` in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then why not simply sum up `EconomyPrice` instead counting the RouteIDs?

```
SELECT
    RouteID,
    SUM(EconomyPrice) AS TotalEconomyPrice
FROM
    [Session6].[dbo].[Schedules]
GROUP BY
    RouteID
ORDER BY
    SUM(EconomyPrice) DESC
```

You cannot have the routes with the highest count and the highest total economy price at the top at the same time, since these conditions might be met by different route Ids. This is not a limitation of SQL. It is simply illogical.

You could also use the average `AVG(EconomyPrice)` as measure.

Comment: Thank you so much i didn't think that